# tabbed application instead or single view application in xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, uistoryboard

I have created a project in Xcode using `UIStoryboard` for the whole design.
It has an `UINavigationController` and a bunch of `UIViewControllers` and I initially used the template Single View Application for my project..
Now midways of developing I have made an important adjustment, I added an `UITabBarController`to the project. It works fine.

Would it be better now to create a new project, with the Tabbed Application template?
It is just a template, right? So probably not necessary to change? Or is it adding some Apple magic to my (now tabbed) project, which I am missing out on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is no need to create a new project.
As you have pointed out it is just a template.

I'm never using any of the templates anymore, just an empty app and I start from there.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not having any trouble you can just go ahead with your project.
As rckoenes said, it's always better to start from a blank project and then insert libraries and code to make sure you'll not have strange errors